# My Panda's DataFrame Replace Function is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python so can't really figure it out. I want to change my 'Class' column in DataFrame 'data' so that values '<=50K' are replaced with 0 and values '>50K' are replaced with 1 so I don't get an error of type mismatch while clustering.

[See The Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReAmy.png)

I have tried to do so in the following snippets:

```
data.replace(to_replace='<=50K',value=0)
data.replace(to_replace='>50K',value=1)
```

and

```
data.replace(to_replace='<=50K',value=0, method ="ffill", inplace=True)
data.replace(to_replace='>50K',value=1, method ="ffill", inplace=True)
```

Any approach to achieve goal other than replacing the string values with integers for clustering will be much appreciated as I cannot think of any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary as reference for `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['<=50K', '>50K'],
                   ['a', '<=50K']])
#        0      1
# 0  <=50K   >50K
# 1      a  <=50K

df = df.replace({'<=50K': 0, '>50K': 1})
```

output:

```
   0  1
0  0  1
1  a  0
```

If acting on a single columns, use `map`:

```
df[0] = df[0].map({'<=50K': 0, '>50K': 1})
```

To handle missing values with a default:

```
d = {'<=50K': 0, '>50K': 1}
df = df.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x, -1))
```

output:

```
   0  1
0  0  1
1 -1  0
```

Comment: It does change the string to float but sets NaN for every instance where these values occur. I tried both solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
# if only one column:
df['Class'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='<=50K' else 0 if x=='>=50K' else x)

# or if you want to apply on the whole dataframe:
df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x=='<=50K' else 0 if x=='>=50K' else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your image, you didn't assign the replaced value to original. You can do

```py
data = data.replace(to_replace='<=50K',value=0)
data = data.replace(to_replace='>50K',value=1)
```

Problem why your `inplace` method doesn't work is that you use the `method` argument which will ignore the `value` argument and use its own strategy to replace the to_replace value, you can use

```py
data.replace(to_replace='>50K',value=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: aah crap. I shared an old screenshot. I actually did figure it out and did exactly what you suggested but it did not change anything.

Comment: @Reznov How is your `Class` column looks like?